# How can I solve a differential equation of the form $c_1 \ddot{x}^2 + c_2 \ddot{x} + c_3 \dot{x}^2-c_4 =0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The solution to it will give us the eqs. of motion of a car moved by a constant force due to combustion of fuel at the engine that produces the main torque at the wheels and that is "fighting" against friction and drag. The differential equation comes from the 2nd law of Newton and the torque equations.

In brief, we'd have
\begin{align*}
\sum F &= m(t) \ddot{x}\\
m(t)\ddot{x} &= F_{fuel} -F_f -F_d = F_{fuel} -\mu m(t)g-\kappa \dot{x}^2
\end{align*}

Since there are two unknown functions we want to find out, $m(t)$ and $x(t)$, $\dot{x}(t)$, or $\ddot{x}(t)$, we'll have to find a relation between $m(t)$ and any of these 3. We'll do it with the torque eqs.. We'll consider that the torque in one of the 4 wheels of the car is generated thanks to $\frac{1}{4}F_f$ and $F_{fuel}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum \tau = r \sin{\theta}\sum F &= I\ddot{\varphi}\\
r(F_{fuel}+\frac{1}{4}F_f) &= \frac{1}{2}m_w r^2 \ddot{\varphi}\\
F_{fuel}+\frac{1}{4}\mu m(t)g &= \frac{1}{2}m_w \ddot{x}\\
m(t) &= \frac{2 m_w}{\mu g} \ddot{x} -\frac{4}{\mu g}F_{fuel}
\end{align*}

Now we substitute this expression in the Newton's equation and get the differential equation from the title for $c_1 \equiv \frac{2 m_w}{\mu g}$, $c_2 \equiv 2m_w -\frac{4}{\mu g} F_{fuel}$, $c_3 \equiv \kappa$, and $c_4 \equiv 5 F_{fuel}$:
\begin{align*}
\Bigg[\frac{2 m_w}{\mu g} \ddot{x} -\frac{4}{\mu g}F_{fuel}\Bigg]\ddot{x} &= F_{fuel} -\mu g \Bigg[\frac{2 m_w}{\mu g} \ddot{x} -\frac{4}{\mu g}F_{fuel}\Bigg]-\kappa \dot{x}^2\\
\frac{2 m_w}{\mu g} \ddot{x}^2 -\frac{4}{\mu g}F_{fuel}\ddot{x} &= F_{fuel} -2 m_w\ddot{x} + 4F_{fuel}-\kappa \dot{x}^2\\
\frac{2 m_w}{\mu g} \ddot{x}^2 + (2m_w -\frac{4}{\mu g} F_{fuel})\ddot{x} + \kappa \dot{x}^2 -5 F_{fuel}&= 0
\end{align*}

I don't have the enough knowledge to approach this diff. eq. yet, and I don't even know if it is solvable analitically.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution to try is linear solution $\dot{x} = c$.  Might be a good place to start.  Does it make sense physically?

Comment: Substitute $y=x'$ then  its separable and reduce to first oder DE

Comment: @Doug The car would go at constant speed even with drag and friction, so yeah a little odd.

Comment: To solve the last equation in Fabian's answer you will need (I believe) the method of 'integration by differentiation'. This will yield a parametric solution which is fairly nice!

Comment: @EliBartlett, can you please elaborate?  I'd be curious to know if you can reduce the answer to a parametric equation without integral.

Comment: @Doug I'll take Fabian's final equation as $F(x')=t$ to keep this comment length. Denote $x'=\xi$, so $t=F(\xi)$. Taking a derivative (or simply using the equation before it was integrated) we find that $\mathrm dt=F(\xi)'\mathrm d\xi$ or $\mathrm dx=\xi F(\xi)'\mathrm d\xi$. Integrating we arrive at $x=\smallint \xi F(\xi)'\mathrm d\xi$. The integral for $\xi F(\xi)'$ is simpler than $F(\xi)$ is! The parametric solution is then
\begin{align}
t=F(\xi),\quad x=\int\xi F(\xi)'\mathrm d\xi.
\end{align}

Comment: @EliBartlett If you want I can mark yours as a solution too; it might help.

Comment: Yes, one problem for Fabian's integral is that when I compute it and I want to isolate the velocity, I can't since it is found inside separate arctan and logarithmic functions. I guess this solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will concentrate on the solution of the ODE $c_1 \ddot{x}^2 + c_2 \ddot{x} + c_3 \dot{x}^2-c_4 =0$ without comment/reference to the physics in the post. I do not believe that the solution can be obtained explicitly. However, some analytical progress can be made.

Let us set $v = \dot x$. Then we need to solve the first order equation
$$c_1 \dot{v}^2 + c_2 \dot{v} + c_3 v^2-c_4 =0\,. \tag{1}$$
This equation is solvable by separation of variables.

Starting from (1), we obtain the expression
$$ \dot v = - \frac{c_2 \pm \sqrt{c_2^2 + 4 c_1 c_4 -4 c_1 c_2 v}}{2 c_1} $$
for the acceleration. The initial condition will typically tell, which of the two solutions you should take. We can integrate the equation with the result
$$ \int_{v_0}^{v} \frac{dv'}{c_2 \pm \sqrt{c_2^2 + 4 c_1 c_4 -4 c_1 c_2 v'^2}} = - 2 c_1 (t-t_0)$$
which implicitly determines $v(t)$. In particular, the integral can be [evaluated in terms of elementary functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%28c2+%2B+Sqrt%5Bc2%5E2+%2B+4+c1+c4+-+4+c1+c3+v%5E2%5D%29%2C+v%5D).

The remaining step is then to integrate $v(t)$ to obtain the position $x(t)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW I think you messed up on $\dot{v}$. It should be $\dot{v} = \frac{-c_2 \pm \sqrt{c^2_2 - 4c_1(c_3v^2-c^4)}}{2 c_1}$. In yours there's no $c_3$, nor $c_4$, nor $v^2$.

Comment: The right hand side corresponding to the integral of time is $\frac{\Delta t}{2 c_1}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's the parametric solution. Starting from where Fabian has left off,
\begin{align}\tag{1}
t=t_0-\frac{1}{2c_1}\int_{x'_0}^{x'} \frac{\mathrm dv}{c_2\pm\sqrt{c_2^2+4c_1 c_4-4c_1 c_2v^2}},\quad\longrightarrow \quad t=t_0+F(x').
\end{align}
Taking $\xi=x'$, taking a derivative of equation (1), and substituting $\mathrm dt=\mathrm dx/\xi$ we find that \begin{align}
\mathrm dx&=\xi F(\xi)'\mathrm d\xi,\\
x&=x_0+\int_{x'_0}^\xi sF(s)'\mathrm ds.
\end{align}
This integral comes out a little shorter than the first! I'll leave it to you to sort out the detailsThe parametric solution is then given by
\begin{align}
t=t_0+F(\xi),\quad x=x_0+\int_{x_0'}^{\xi}sF(s)'\mathrm ds.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. When I compute the integral I get $-\dfrac{c_2\ln\Big|\sqrt{-4c_1c_3v^2+4c_1c_4+c_2^2}-c_2\Big|+\sqrt{-4c_1c_3v^2+4c_1c_4+c_2^2}}{4c_1c_3} = x$. If I want to find the velocity in terms of x, how'd I isolate $v$? Using Lambert W function?

Comment: That integral gives you a function of the dummy variable $\xi$, not $v$. But I believe you can solve for $\xi$ as you’ve described and substitute that into $F(\xi)$ to get an implicit solution $t=\phi(x)$!

Comment: I did. And I actually could isolate v. The problem is differentiating it in terms of time to get the acceleration...